# Profile image not loaded correctly

Tags: discussion, bug

This is my profile image which looks correctly on the profile tab.
[image]

The same image is partially loaded on the header.

even on refreshing multiple times,it doesn't load fully on Windows7 +Chrome

May I know why?

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu 14.04, on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Maybe that's because smoking is prohibite in the lobby :)

Comment: Clear your cache.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/  _had to post this_

Answer (score 2):

Clear your cache.

Apparently, that image didn't load properly, and is now cached as a partially loaded image.